# Dynamic Range division with two variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to complete division for a dynamic range with two variables and it keeps dividing the dynamic range by the last number in the range. Below is my VBA code.

```
 For i = 2 To 8
     For r = 13 To 19
         If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 28) = "" Then
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 28) = ""
         Else
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, 28) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 28) / Range("$AB$8")
         End If
     Next r
 Next i
```

Essentially it is dividing the last i value (Cell row 8) by the Range("$AB$8") (cells row 19).

What I would like to happen is the values in rows i to divide by Range("$AB$8")....in other words the value in cell (2,28)/ab8, (3/28)/ab8, (4,28)/ab8 etc etc.
It current is taking the value in cell (8,28) dividing it by ab8...and applying it to all defined r rows.

Comment: You have hard-coded `Range("$AB$8")` - is this the problem?

Comment: @SJR it is not. The issue is that it is not going in sequential order of dividing the next i value by the hard-coded cell. rows 2 through 8 should essentially be dividing by the $AB$8 value

Comment: I think you need to add some more details on what you want to have happen. Your code seems to match what you've described is happening. We can't really tell you how that's wrong without details on what you want.

Comment: @JoshEller updated. Let me know if you need more information

Comment: What's the nested loop meant to be doing? Each iteration of the outer `i` loop is going to over-write the previous loop's results, and you'll wind up just seeing the final results from `i = 8`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @JoshEller I do not intend on overwriting results

Comment: Is the whole `r` loop meant to put the results from row `i` in row `i + 6`? If so, just get rid of the `For r = 13 To 19` loop entirely, and instead define `r = i + 6`.

Comment: @JoshEller that fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here - all of which are small tweaks but end up with the wrong result you are seeing.

Your example code is not a dynamic range. You have hardcoded Cells(AB2:AB8) and Cells(AB13:AB19). You just did it in a way that is not obvious.

Also not very obvious is that you are writing the results to a single column. See the pattern here:

- Loop 1: i = 2, results may be writing to Cells(AB13:AB19)
- […]
- Loop 7: i = 8, results may be writing to Cells(AB13:AB19)

I said "may" because you have the `If` statement.

Depending on what you really want to happen, the code can be amended.

- Instead off the first loop put a conditional there (e.g. If all cells
  in that range are blank then …, or if any cells are blank then ...)
- Use an `Exit For` after fixing the first blank loop
- Also address the column (i.e. results spread across multiple columns)
- Use a single loop (`For i = 2 to 8` … and then adjust `r` according to `i`… `r = i+12`)